# White-Test: Use F-Statistic or LM-statistic?

Tags: regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity, white-test

to interpret the White-Test, it is recommended to use the LM-statistic = N*R-squared of the auxiliary regression which follows a Chi-squared distribution with df = number of restrictions.

But I wondered why. Wouldn't it be just fine to use the F-Test? The null hypothesis of the F-Test would be that all parameters of the auxiliary regression are 0 (excluding the constant). Of course, we have interactions terms and explanatory variables^2 , but the restrictions of the null hypothesis are still linear: ß_1 = ß_2 = ... = 0. So I don't see a problem using the F-statistic. And the advantage of the F-statistic would be that we don't rely on the asymptotic properties of LM-tests.

Why isn't this done normally? Why is only the LM-statistic used for the White test?

Comment: Hi: According to the link below, you can use an F-test. But the F-test statistic is not the you'd get from a test of $\beta_i = 0 ~\forall i $. This probably has something to do with the fact that White's test has squares and products of the $X_i$ in the regression where $\epsilon^2_{i}$ is the response so one can't use the regular F-test because there are other terms in there.  The standard F-test assumes one just has single coefficients in the model.   https://www.dummies.com/article/business-careers-money/business/economics/test-for-heteroskedasticity-with-the-white-test-154899

Answer (score 1):

You can use an asymptotic F-test just fine. In fact, for an asymptotic F-test we have:

$F=\frac{LM}{n-LM}\frac{n-k}{q}\overset{d}{\rightarrow}F\left ( q, n-k \right )$

so it won't be a much different concept anyway.

> And the advantage of the F-statistic would be that we don't rely on
> the asymptotic properties of LM-tests.

It seems that your confusion stems from wanting to use an exact statistic as opposed to an approximate statistic. If you want to go down that route - be my guest, however, you often fail to to know the exact distribution of the statistic when the assumptions involved are not met. Moreover, «exact» does not mean much on its own and certainly [does not automatically equal «better»](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Eaa/articles/agresti_coull_1998.pdf).